# Set a variable value to the clicked button with a form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form with 8 buttons, like this:

```css
.settings-theme-buttons{
    height: 4vw;
    width: 4vw;
    
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#settings-theme-white{
    background: #ddd;
}

#settings-theme-red{
    background: #b83b5e;
}

#settings-theme-blue{
    background: #51adcf;
}

#settings-theme-green{
    background: #b6eb7a;
}

#settings-theme-green{
    background: #b6eb7a;
}

#settings-theme-orange{
    background: #ff9234;
}

#settings-theme-yellow{
    background: #ffd36b;
}

#settings-theme-purple{
    background: #8675a9;
}

#settings-theme-pink{
    background: #efbbcf;
}
```

```html
<form action="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
<button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" id="settings-theme-white" name="white-option"></button>
<button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" style="color: #ddd;" id="settings-theme-red" name="red-option"></button>
<button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" id="settings-theme-blue" name="blue-option"></button>
<button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" id="settings-theme-green" name="green-option"></button>
<button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" id="settings-theme-orange" name="orange-option"></button>
<button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" id="settings-theme-yellow" name="yellow-option"></button>
<button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" id="settings-theme-purple" name="purple-option"></button>
<button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" id="settings-theme-pink" name="pink-option"></button>
</form>
```

As you can see, each button has a name depending on its color, like, "white-option". With PHP what I want to do is to set a variable value to based on the button that was clicked. For example, if the `white-option` button was clicked, I want to set the variable to, "white", and if the red button was clicked, I want to set the variable to, "red", etc...

How can I do this with PHP?

Comment: Are you sure you want to achieve this in PHP, on the server?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is only css, with pseudo class selector

example:

```
 /* unvisited link */
a:link {
  color: #FF0000;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
  color: #00FF00;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
  color: #FF00FF;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
  color: #0000FF;
}
```

please visit: 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you add a value to each button you can call it back with the name of the button:

This is an example for the white button

```
<button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" id="settings-theme-white" name="white-option" value="pressed white"></button>
```

Then get the variable in PHP with this code:

```
<?php
$white = $_REQUEST['white-option'];
echo $white;
?>
```

When you press the white button the value 'pressed white' will be stored in $white. Just expand this out for all your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can POST the buttons value using the name. If you only want one value then set the name to something like `color` and set your individual buttons values to their colors.

`<button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" id="settings-theme-white" value="white-option" name="color">White</button>`

Then when the button is pressed the value will be posted tot he POST global for `['color']`, make sure the post value is set and then set your variable to its value...

HTML

```html
<form action="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" id="settings-theme-white" value="white" name="color">White</button>
    <button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" id="settings-theme-red" value="red"name="color">Red</button>
    <button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" id="settings-theme-blue" value="blue" name="color">Blue</button>
    <button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" id="settings-theme-green" value="green" name="color">Green</button>
    <button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" id="settings-theme-orange" value="orange" name="color">Orange</button>
    <button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" id="settings-theme-yellow" value="yellow" name="color">Yellow</button>
    <button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" id="settings-theme-purple" value="purple" name="color">Purple</button>
    <button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons" id="settings-theme-pink" value="pink" name="color">Pink</button>    
</form>
```

PHP

```php
if(isset($_POST['color'])){
    $color = $_POST['color']; // $color now holds the value of your submission
}
```

You could do this using vanilla Javascript without ever refreshing the page and sending anything to the server... Just get the elements using a class selector. Then run the elements through a for loop using an incrementor and .length to loop over the element list. Set up an event listener using the element and its indexed position to find the element being clicked on. Get the elements `textContent` and then save it to a variable.

```js
const colors = document.querySelectorAll('.colors');
const selectedColor = document.getElementById('selectedColor');

for(let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++){
    colors[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let color = colors[i].textContent; // your selected color now resides in this JS variable
        selectedColor.textContent = color;
    })
}
```

```html
<form action="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
  <button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons colors" id="settings-theme-white" value="white-option" name="color">White</button>
  <button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons colors" id="settings-theme-red" value="red-option" name="color">Red</button>
  <button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons colors" id="settings-theme-blue" value="blue-option" name="color">Blue</button>
  <button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons colors" id="settings-theme-green" value="green-option" name="color">Green</button>
  <button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons colors" id="settings-theme-orange" value="orange-option" name="color">Orange</button>
  <button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons colors" id="settings-theme-yellow" value="yellow-option" name="color">Yellow</button>
  <button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons colors" id="settings-theme-purple" value="purple-option" name="color">Purple</button>
  <button type="submit" class="settings-theme-buttons colors" id="settings-theme-pink" value="pink-option" name="color">Pink</button>
</form>
<div id="selectedColor"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["color"])){
$color=$_POST["color"];
if($color==="white-option")
$color="white";
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">

<input type="submit" name="color" value="white-option">
</form>
```